# How to set HSTS header from .htaccess to force loading assets via https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-headers

After switching to https and adding following lines to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000" env=HTTPS
```

Everything seems to be working fine - even if someone type http://mywebsite.com will be redirected to https://.

However, as per my understanding, HSTS should also enforce all content to be loaded via https if possible. Unfortunately, every now and then if someone makes a mistake and load some image (hosted on the same domain) via http:// instead of https:// Chrome will show a mixed content warning.

Did I make some mistake or my understanding of HSTS is wrong?